# Flutter: Provider: Consumer widget rebuild with updated data, but does not repaint ListView containing elements

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I love Provider/Consumers, it has changed the flutter game for me. However, there are rare occurrences I've noticed when using Consumer where notifyListener does not repaint the widget. I've once fixed this using a GlobalKey for the Widget consuming the data, but this time it does not help.

I want to get a better understanding of Consumer/Provider by understanding why this particular widget is failing to repaint. I even have a print that shows that the widget has the updated data.

```
class ActivityFeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<_ActivityFeedPageState> key = GlobalKey<_ActivityFeedPageState>();

  ActivityFeedPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ActivityFeedPageState createState() => _ActivityFeedPageState();
}

class _ActivityFeedPageState extends State<ActivityFeedPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageLayout(
      title: 'ACTIVITY',
      buttonTitle: 'extend',
      buttonFunc:
          Provider.of<ActivityFeed>(context, listen: false).extendActivityFeed,
      child: Consumer<ActivityFeed>(
        builder: (ctx, activityFeed, child) {
          print('activities length = ${activityFeed.activityFeedItems}');
          return ListView(
            children: activityFeed.activityFeedItems,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PageLayout is a simple page formatting widget I use throughout the app, which i do not want to rebuild.

So first run though, there are two initial elements that paint correctly. Once I 'extend' the feed, the print shows me that there are now four elements. The listview still only shows the original two.

It is curious to me that this issue arose in the past with ListView as well. I'm wondering if ListView has some unique efficiency preventing the rebuild with the new elements after a notifyListeners() call?

Cheers!

EDIT: ******************************************************

I should add that this ActivityFeedPage is nested in a parent PageView. When I move the Consumer up to that PageView and pass 'activityFeed' to ActivityFeedPage as an argument the widget repaints correctly on notifyListeners()

Would this mean that even though I am viewing ActivityFeedPage, it is not the main active widget on my screen? And my parent PageView is the lowest active widget?

Source: I navigated away and back to ActivityFeedPage and the new elements were shown. This gave me a clue that ActivityFeedPage didn't know to repaint.

Comment: I think you don't need to pass listen as false

Comment: For that particular line, I am only connecting the 'extend' function that exists in the class. This function does not change, it is only a pointer to the func